# Number of comparisons for quick sort

Tags: haskell

Here is an implementation of quick sort which is considered to be "not real quick":

```
qSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
qSort [] = []
qSort (p:xs) = (qSort $ filter (< p) xs) ++ (qSort $ filter (== p) xs) ++ [p] ++ (qSort $ filter (> p) xs)

main = print $ qSort [15, 11, 9, 25, -3]
```

But nonetheless, is it possible to count the number of comparisons needed to make  it done? I tried to count the size of `filter (< p) xs` and `filter (> p) xs` but I turned out to not be what I needed.

**UPDATE**:

The question is not about time complexity, it's exactly about counting the number of comparisons.

Comment: Note that the algorithm is wrong, for example for the sequence `[15,11,9,15,-3]`.

Comment: Please explain what you did to try to count the number of comparisons.

Comment: Remember that `(==p)` is a comparison also, so you should count how many times it is used as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others said, a direct translation is to modify your algorithm to use a monad, which will count the comparisons. Instead of `State` I'd rather use `Writer`, because it describes more naturally what's happening: Each result is augmented with the (additive) number of comparisons that it required:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Writer.Strict
import Data.Monoid

type CountM a = Writer (Sum Int) a
```

Then let's define a function that wraps a pure value into a monadic one that increments the counter:

```
count :: Int -> a -> CountM a
count c = (<$ tell (Sum c))
```

Now we can define

```
qSortM :: Ord a => [a] -> CountM [a]
qSortM [] = return []
qSortM (p:xs) =
   concatM [ qSortM =<< filtM (<  p)
           , filtM (== p)
           , return [p]
           , qSortM =<< filtM (>  p)
           ]
  where
    filtM p = filterM (count 1 . p) xs
    concatM :: (Monad m) => [m [a]] -> m [a]
    concatM = liftM concat . sequence
```

It's not as nice as the original version, but still usable.

---

Note that you compare each element of the list three times, while it's enough to do it once. This has another unfortunate consequence that the original list has to be kept in memory until all three filters finish. So let's instead define

```
-- We don't care we reverse the order of elements in the buckets,
-- we'll sort them later anyway.
split :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a], [a], Int)
split p = foldl f ([], [], [], 0)
  where
    f (ls, es, gs, c) x = case compare x p of
        LT  -> (x : ls, es, gs, c')
        EQ  -> (ls, x : es, gs, c')
        GT  -> (ls, es, x : gs, c')
      where
        c' = c `seq` c + 1
```

This performs the splitting into the three buckets all at once and also computes the length of the list, so we can update the counter at once. The list is consumed at once and can be discarded by the garbage collector.

Now our quicksort will get a bit leaner

```
qSortM :: Ord a => [a] -> CountM [a]
qSortM [] = return []
qSortM (p:xs) = count c =<<
    concatM [ qSortM ls
            , return (p : es)
            , qSortM gs
            ]
  where
    (ls, es, gs, c) = split p xs
    concatM = liftM concat . sequence
```

We could have reached the same result without using the `Writer`, just by having `qSortM` return `(Int, [a])` explicitly. But then we would have to manually process the results of recursive `qSortM`, which would be quite more messy. Moreover, the monadic way allows us to add later more information, such as the maximum depth, without disrupting the core part in any way.

Comment: You probably already know this, but `type CompareM = Writer (Sum Int)` is a more flexible way to define this synonym.  In particular, it allows this synonym to be used with monad transformers.  I understand the expansion for expository purposes, though.

Comment: First of all, I think `CompareM` is an odd name, wouldn't `CountM` be more sensible? Secondly, why is `split` not in the writer monad, and why doesn't it just use `tell`?

Comment: @BenMillwood Yes, `CountM` is much better, I'll update the answer. I don't know why I chose `CompareM`.  Yes, making `split` to be `splitM :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> CountM ([a], [a], [a])` would be a valid option. I prefer to have pure functions, if possible, because then they can be used more flexibly, but your way would have the advantage of hiding counting completely.

Answer (score 3):

Thinking about the question theoretically, as Monad Newb proposed in their answer is probably the best way to think about what your algorithm actually does.

There's of course the silly way of just sticking the comparison into a `State` monad. This will just brute-force count every invocation of the comparison function. Note the use of the `count` action, which just transforms a predicate into an action that that keeps track of each invocation of said predicate, and then applies it to its argument.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Monad.State

qSortM :: Ord a => [a] -> State Int [a]
qSortM [] = return []
qSortM (p:xs) = do h <- (qSortM =<< filterM (count (< p)) xs)
                   e <- (qSortM =<< filterM (count (== p)) xs)
                   t <- (qSortM =<< filterM (count (> p)) xs)
                   return $ h ++ e ++ [p] ++ t
               where count :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> State Int Bool)
                     count p a = modify (+1) >> return (p a)

qSort :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a],Int)
qSort l = runState (qSortM l) 0

main :: IO ()
main = print $ (qSort [15, 11, 9, 25, -3])
```

This is actually terrible Haskell, and can be expressed without the `State` monad, just by using recursive functions. A good exercise would be to write it this way. Admittedly, the `State` monad version will make more intuitive sense to people coming from an imperative background.

```
> qSort [10,9..1]
([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],90)

> qSort [15,11,9,25,-3]
([-3,9,11,15,25],14)
```

Comment: Continuing the calculations in my edited answer, I get 19 comparisons. I wonder why my answer differs from then one that your code gives...

Comment: Neither 14 or 19 can be correct, because the number must be divisible by 3. I think it should be 18.

Comment: what do `=<<` and `<-` mean what are their names?

Comment: `(=<<)` is reversed `(>>=)` i.e. reversed "bind" `(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`. `(<-)` doesn't have a name, it's just a part of `do` notation. It translates to bind/`(>>=)` itself.

Comment: I think this is a perfect place to use a monad, actually -- it's a computation enriched with effects.  Except `State` is the wrong one -- this is absolutely a scenario for `Writer` and the [`Sum`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Data-Monoid.html#v:Sum) monoid.

Comment: @tel, `(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> (m a -> m b)`, which is an extension along `return` (i.e. finds a `g` such that `g . return = f`), so "extend" seems like a good name.  Also, it has the same argument order and plays the role of application in monadic computations, so "apply" could also be a good name for it.

Comment: I... really like "extend". The notation is too obviously suggestive of a direction of flow and relation with `(>>=)`, but I love that intuition. I wish we could define `f* = (f =<<)`.

Comment: please tell me the names of `=<<` and `<-` and I'll be able to google them. Or give a link where they are described please.

Comment: @luqui, you're correct, the `Writer` Monad would be the better fit here. @Marius Kavansky: `=<<` is the same as `bind`, or `>>=`, it just takes its arguments the other way around. I could've written the above code as `e <- (filterM (count (== p)) xs >>= qSortM)` instead, it would have been semantically equivalent. The following equality holds `p =<< q === q >>= p`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's evaluate the expression `qSort [15, 11, 9, 25, -3]`:

```
qSort [15, 11, 9, 25, -3]
    = qSort (15:[11, 9, 25, -3])
    = (qSort $ filter (< 15) [11, 9, 25, -3])
      ++ (qSort $ filter (== 15) [11, 9, 25, -3])
      ++ [p]
      ++ (qSort $ filter (> 15) [11, 9, 25, -3])
    = (qSort [11, 9, -3]) ++ (qSort []) ++ [p] ++ (qSort [25])
```

To get this far, we have done 12 comparisons. You can evaluate the remaining applications of `qSort` in a similar manner.

Note that this kind of substitution is valid because we are using so-called pure functional programming here. There are no side effects, so any expression can be substituted with an equivalent one.

Comment: doesn't it depend on the algorithm of choosing a pivot element?

Comment: @MariusKavansky The algorithm you quoted just chooses the first element.

Comment: @AndrewC, it does it only for simplicity, I'll change it later.

Answer (score 1):

We can just write the function to calculate this number. Each `filter p xs` performs `length xs` comparisons, that's all.

Right now your code performs 3 passes to perform the partition; you could re-write it to perform the three-way partition in one pass. We can make the number of passes a parameter.

Another thing is the needless sorting of the middle section, which is already known to contain all equal elements. We can make it a parameter too, to signal whether this needless sorting is performed or not.

```
_NoSort = False
_DoSort = True

qsCount xs n midSortP = qs 0 xs id     -- return number of comparisons that 
 where                                 -- n-pass `qSort xs` would perform
   qs !i []     k = k i
   qs !i (p:xs) k = 
     let (a,b,c) = (filter (< p) xs, filter (== p) xs, filter (> p) xs)
     in qs (i+n*length xs) a (\i-> g i b (\i-> qs i c k))
   g i b k | midSortP  = qs i b k 
           | otherwise = k i
```

as can be seen, it will take 3x more comparisons with 3 passes than with 1, and the middle sorting can only make any difference if there are more than two equal elements in the list:

```
*Main> qsCount ( concat $ replicate 4 [10,9..1]) 3 _NoSort
630
*Main> qsCount ( concat $ replicate 4 [10,9..1]) 3 _DoSort
720
*Main> qsCount ( concat $ replicate 4 [10,9..1]) 1 _NoSort
210
*Main> qsCount ( concat $ replicate 4 [10,9..1]) 1 _DoSort
240
*Main> qsCount [5,3,8,4,10,1,6,2,7,9] 1 _NoSort
19
*Main> qsCount [5,3,8,4,10,1,6,2,7,9] 1 _DoSort
19
*Main> qsCount (replicate 10 1) 1 _NoSort
9
*Main> qsCount (replicate 10 1) 1 _DoSort
45
*Main> qsCount [15, 11, 9, 25, -3] 3 _DoSort
21
```

Comment: @MariusKavansky add the line `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}` at the start of the file and it will work. You can [read about bang patterns e.g. here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html) BTW. Basically, bang (!) marks a variable that is to be made *strict* (eagerly evaluated, i.e. not lazy).